# Trying to find a way to implement a nested transaction for my project

Tags: c#, ado.net

I recently created a light weight ORM tool in C# and posted it on  [Github](https://www.github.com/RiceRiceBaby/ADOCRUD). One of the things my ORM does is manage the opening and closing of connections for you along with opening and disposing of a sql transaction. The way I do this is I open the connection and begin the sql transaction in the constructor of my context class and close the connection and dispose the transaction on the dispose method of my context class. The code below are some methods from my tool:

```
public class ADOCRUDContext : IDisposable
{
    internal IDbConnection sqlConnection;
    internal IDbTransaction sqlTransaction;

    internal string suffix = "_";

    public ADOCRUDContext(string connectionString)
    {            
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        sqlTransaction.Commit();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes transaction and closes sql connection
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        sqlTransaction.Dispose();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }

    public void Insert<T>(T item)
    {
        string tableName = ObjectTypeHelper.GetTableName<T>(item);

        // Properties of object that are not primary keys
        PropertyInfo[] modelProperties = ObjectTypeHelper.GetModelProperties<T>(item, false);

        // Properties of object that are also primary keys
        PropertyInfo[] primaryKeyProperties = ObjectTypeHelper.GetPrimaryKeyProperties<T>(item);

        if (modelProperties == null || modelProperties.Count() == 0)
        {
            // Moves composite keys to model properties if they are the only properties of the table/object
            if (primaryKeyProperties.Count() > 0)
                modelProperties = primaryKeyProperties;
            else
                throw new Exception("Class has no properties or are missing Member attribute");
        }

        // Generates insert statement
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("insert into " + tableName + "(" + String.Join(",", modelProperties.Select(x => x.Name)) + ") ");
        query.Append("values (" + String.Join(", ", modelProperties.Select(x => "@" + x.Name+suffix)) + ") ");
        query.Append("select @primaryKey = @@identity");

        try
        { 
            // Generates and executes sql command 
            SqlCommand cmd = GenerateSqlCommand<T>(item, query.ToString(), modelProperties, null, ADOCRUDEnums.Action.Insert, suffix);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Loads db generated identity value into property with primary key attribute
            // if object only has 1 primary key
            // Multiple primary keys = crosswalk table which means property already contains the values
            if (primaryKeyProperties != null && primaryKeyProperties.Count() == 1)
                primaryKeyProperties[0].SetValue(item, cmd.Parameters["primaryKey"].Value as object);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Below is an example of how you use my tool:

```
public void AddProduct(Product p)
{
  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
  {
    context.Insert<Product>(p);
    context.Commit();
  }
}

public void UpdateProduct(int productId)
{
  using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
  {
    Product p = this.GetProductById(productId);
    p.Name = "Basketball";
    context.Update<Product>(p);
    context.Commit();
  }
}
```

Currently if I do something like:

```
public void DoSomething(Product p)
{
    using (ADOCRUDContext context = new ADOCRUDContext(connectionString))
    {
        this.AddProduct(p);
        p.Name = "Test";
        throw new Exception("Blah");
    }
}
```

Even though I threw an exception on DoSomething, the product still got added to the database since the inner transaction was committed. Is there a way to get the inner transaction (AddProduct) to fail if the outer transaction fails?

Comment: One product I used to work on had a similar database utility. It kept a thread-static transaction reference count and performed the actual commit or rollback when the last transaction completed. Another option is to query the transaction count from the database. For example, SQL Server has `@@TRANCOUNT`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx

Comment: That would mean I would have to remove my commit method because I would have to force a commit after the last transaction every time. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you'd change your commit method to track the number of open transactions and only perform the actual commit in the database when the last one is committed.

Comment: I was doing some research on reference counting and they say that there's no reliable to way to get all the references of an object in c#.